# Download files Git repo

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-api

I have a log file in my repo. for every component its a different one but called all the same (log.txt) I want to download these log files from a **specific (sha/gittag)**. Because I need the specific version of this files.

Because of the same name, i thout about saving the component names (comp1 etc.) before the log files. comp1_log.txt. In the end I will have a log.zip.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
Tool/
├── comp1/ 
│   ├── log.txt
└── comp2/
    ├── log.txt
    comp3/
    ├── log.txt
```

**My question:** How can I get these files with this condition (specific sha or gittag)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading the repo as an archive?

`https://<gitlab_url>/archive/<commit-hash>/<file-name>.zip`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I didnt get how to do it. Where should I write this. Could u do an example?